# GNOME Terminal: Connect via SSH from Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 into Ubuntu Server 14.04 Virtual Box Guest Host

Tags: networking, server, ssh

**Here are my current conditions:**

- I have UBUNTU DESKTOP on HARD DISK. (I don't use windows)
- Desktop has ssh installed.
- Ifnet: 192.168.1.3
- Username: kenneth
- I want Desktop to be the client.
- VirtualBox Newtork is configured as bridge mode.
- I Installed UBUNTU SERVER 14.04 on VirtualBox and I configured ifnet 192.168.1.10. (I want this one as the server)
- I have installed openssh for server as well
- Username kenneth1
- I open GNOME-Terminal and do:

  ```
  kenneth@kenneth-Inspiron-5558:~$ ssh 192.168.1.10
  kenneth@192.168.1.10's password:(here I type the password which is correct of course)
  Permission denied, please try again.
  ```

I want to manage Server from terminal on my Desktop Gnome Terminal.

What seems to be the problem?

[image]

It worked:

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: Does the virtual machine have a user named `kenneth`? I see `kenneth1`.

Comment: the virtual machine's user name is kenneth1, my desktop's user is kenneth

Comment: Then do `ssh kenneth1@192...`.

Comment: @muru It worked thank you, See second image:  http://askubuntu.com/users/158442/muru

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a different username on the system you are connecting to, you have to specify it:

```
ssh kenneth1@192.168.1.10
```

If you don't specify any username, SSH assumes your current username.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want to do is to set up port forwarding, to connect a specific port of your HOST to GUEST. Here's an example of my Deepin VM:

[image]

In this case, the HOST (Ubuntu 14.04) is a physical machine on my local network.  When I do `ssh -p 2222 admin@192.168.0.222` I am connecting to port 2222 of my HOST machine. The host machine will make connection to port 22 of your GUEST.

In your example, what you'd want to do is set up port forwarding , `192.168.1.3` port 2222 to GUEST IP (whatever you've)