# How do I 'scp' between a virtual appliances that are running on different computers?

Tags: networking, server, virtualbox, ssh

Both computers are running their copy of the same virtual appliance on Virtual Box which is accessed through putty.exe.

I would like to scp a C++ program that I've written on one of the virtual image (VM1) to another computer's virtual image (VM2) across a network:

[VM1] --> [Host Computer 1]--> Internet --> [Host Computer 2] --> [VM2]

I'm pretty newbish and this may be an involved solution and I don't expect the nice folks in this forum to do everything for me. However, if you could point me to the right resources, much will be appreciated :).

Comment: Well, you need to set up port forwarding on that other VM2, so that you can connect to it in the first place. I've posted a relevant answer before, will link it here

Comment: This explains how to set up port forwarding to the VM: http://askubuntu.com/a/727243/295286

Answer (score 0):

You say you want to scp - then the information is accessed through *man scp* or *info scp*  form a command prompt - or you can google scp

the man pages can be a bit daunting it says

> scp [-12346BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file]
>            [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program]
>            [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

so here is my short version of it

*scp* is a bit like "copy from_existing_file to_non_existing"
thus a simple version of it would be "scp  myid@remotehost:myprog.cpp mycopy.cpp"
if you wan to "grab" a copy
or
  "scp  myprog.cpp myid@remotehost:mycopy.cpp"
if you want to store away a backup-copy
all the other switches like -v  depend on your setup - and various issues.

Good Luck